# Get actual CPU speed when using dynamic CPU scaling

Tags: linux, bash

I need a way to get the actual CPU(hardware) speed(maxspeed) when using dynamic CPU freq. scaling. Reading /proc/cpuinfo does not work as it shows the current step in scaling. Also the min-max frequencies in CPU scaling are configurable so reading " /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq" will not do it, I need a reliable way.

Example : 
  My model shows "Intel(R) ****** CPU 3.66GHz" but the min-max of freq scaling can be configured(say 500MHZ to 2.3GHZ). How can I get the 3.66GHZ value ?